# Setting up certain fields before creating a user through devise + rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I am trying to add some fields to the user after the user has registered and I am using devise.

This is the code which I am trying to put in RegistrationsController

```
 if resource.save
            address_1 = resource.address.split(',')
            resource.city = address[0]
            resource.state = address[1]
```

However after the user registers these fields (city and state appear to be nil).

Can some tell how to properly override the registration controller so that once the user registers I can perform certain action before saving the user in the db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was not giving the controller properly  by giving the overridden controller name in the route file everything is working as expected.